# Showing SliverAppBar only when user stretches

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, sliverappbar

I want to create a SliverAppBar which only shows up when the user stretches it.
I came so far:

```
SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 100,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 246, 254, 1.0),
        elevation: 0.0,
        floating: false,
        snap: false,
        pinned: false,
        stretch: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Refresh"),
            ),
          ),
          stretchModes: [StretchMode.zoomBackground],
        ),
        onStretchTrigger: () {
          print("todo: refresh");
          return;
        },
      ),
```

[i took a screentshot to show what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PwKy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A first basic solution could be to start with an `initialScrollOffset` of E`expandedHeight`:

```
SliverAppBar(
  controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 100),
  expandedHeight: 100,
  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 246, 254, 1.0),
  elevation: 0.0,
  floating: false,
  snap: false,
  pinned: false,
  stretch: true,
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
    background: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Refresh"),
      ),
    ),
    stretchModes: [StretchMode.zoomBackground],
  ),
  onStretchTrigger: () {
    print("todo: refresh");
    return;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';

```
import 'package:example/other/refresh_glowindicator.dart';
import 'package:example/ui/MainActivity.dart';
import 'package:example/ui/SecondActivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';
import 'ui/indicator/base/IndicatorActivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshConfiguration(
      footerTriggerDistance: 15,
      dragSpeedRatio: 0.91,
      headerBuilder: () => MaterialClassicHeader(),
      footerBuilder: () => ClassicFooter(),
      enableLoadingWhenNoData: false,
      enableRefreshVibrate: false,
      enableLoadMoreVibrate: false,
      shouldFooterFollowWhenNotFull: (state) {
        // If you want load more with noMoreData state ,may be you should return false
        return false;
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Pulltorefresh Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return ScrollConfiguration(
            child: child,
            behavior: RefreshScrollBehavior(),
          );
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //s
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
            // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            primaryColor: Colors.greenAccent),
        localizationsDelegates: [
          RefreshLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en'),
          const Locale('zh'),
          const Locale('ja'),
          const Locale('uk'),
          const Locale('it'),
          const Locale('ru'),
          const Locale('fr'),
          const Locale('es'),
          const Locale('nl'),
          const Locale('sv'),
          const Locale('pt'),
          const Locale('ko'),
        ],
        locale: const Locale('zh'),
        localeResolutionCallback:
            (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
          //print("change language");
          return locale;
        },
        home: MainActivity(title: 'Pulltorefresh'),
        routes: {
          "sec": (BuildContext context) {
            return SecondActivity(
              title: "SecondAct",
            );
          },
          "indicator": (BuildContext context) {
            return IndicatorActivity();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```